# MongoDB Installation on Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 32-bit Operating system

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I just installed monodb(version 3.2) at my windows machine. I created D:/data/db directory also. when i give the command "mongod" to start it, it shows the following error.

**Following options were tried**

1.c:\~\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod.exe (Following error stack listed below)

```
2016-02-18T13:29:41.629+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndList
en: 28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not av
ailable with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine exp
licitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating
2016-02-18T13:29:41.629+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

2. c:\~\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod.exe  --storageEngine=mmapv1

   > Same log file shown above
3. I followed the solution given in this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/742230/mongo-db-installation-showing-storage-engine-error), I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storageEngine=mmapv1 is for older version, as you are installed latest version 3.2. So by defaultly if you start your `mongod` wiredTiger files will same inside data/db. So Delete everything from db directory and start freshly with

`mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1`

Whenever you want to switch from one storage engine to another you need to clean your db directory, then only you can swich

For wiredTiger

mongod --storageEngine=wiredTiger or mongod

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mongod --storageEngine=mmapv1 --dbpath "Your Path"`.

For more details Please go through https://technicalforum.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/mongodb-tutorial-part1/